# Where does VSCode get the docstring signature?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, docstring

Where does the VSCode get docstring signatures? I could not find any relevant section in the settings.

In my installation, it is clear that VSCode is not using the signature from the `__doc__` attribute.
I would like to see the `__doc__` (or set it to output of `pydoc`), but I am getting something like below

[image]

Here is the signature I get from `__doc__` or `pydoc`

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Comment: `In: print.__doc__`
`Out: "print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)\n\nPrints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.\nOptional keyword arguments:\nfile:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.\nsep:   string inserted between values, default a space.\nend:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.\nflush: whether to forcibly flush the stream."` This is what I get from `print.__doc__`. Maybe VSCode is using a different python installation?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yes I had checked that, I use the same Python interpreter VSCode is set to (/usr/local/bin/python3). When you hover in VSCode what do you get, do you get the same output of print.__doc__ or you get something like my screenshot?

Comment: What version of Python is it? Probably a version- or platform-specific thing?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I tried with two different systems, one with 3.6 other 3.7, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's pulling them from mypy's stub files as well as a portion of the docstring.

The stub files for builtins and the standard library can be found at. `<python path>\Lib\site-packages\mypy\typeshed\stdlib\`. The print statement in particular can be found in `__builtin__.pyi` in the `2` folder around line `1354`.

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    class _Writer(Protocol):
        def write(self, __s: str) -> Any: ...
    def print(
        *values: object, sep: Optional[Text] = ..., end: Optional[Text] = ..., file: Optional[_Writer] = ..., flush: bool = ...
    ) -> None: ...
```

[Github](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/6a06ff53f0f6974784481d5594ab81e563a93b58/stdlib/2/__builtin__.pyi#L1562) link to the relevant line. This is a newer version so it's not entirely identical.